# Does $\mathbb{P}(\Omega) = 1$ have to apply uniquely only for $\Omega$?

Tags: measure-theory

In axiom 3 (or sometimes 2) of probability measures.

Does $\mathbb{P}(\Omega) = 1$ have to apply uniquely only for $\Omega$ or can $\mathbb{P} (S) =1$ also for some $S \subset \Omega$?

Comment: Imagine you are throwing darts. Assuming you never miss the board, what is the probability of missing the center (center being one point, not a circle around center)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to have $\mathbb{P}(S)=1$ for proper (measurable) subsets $S\subset \Omega$.

Consider for instance $\Omega=[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure. If $S=[0,1)$ then $\mathbb{P}(S)=1$. More generally, $\mathbb{P}(S)=1$ if $S=[0,1]\setminus C$ for $C$ a countable set. (We could also remove more complicated sets like the Cantor set).

For a completely different example, suppose that $\Omega=\mathbb{Z}$, and define $\mathbb{P}(S)=1$ if $0\in S$, and $\mathbb{P}(S)=0$ otherwise. This is a probability law on $\Omega$ which has lots of proper subsets $S$ with $\mathbb{P}(S)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a space with finite measure, you can normalize the measure so that it's measure $1$. Now the complement of any null set has measure $1$, yet is not the whole space.